# Sectional curvature of orbits generated by an isometric action

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group acting isometrically on a pseudo-riemannian manifold, $M$. I need a practical way to calculate the sectional curvature of the orbits at any point. Actually, I have some explicit examples which I have to calculate their sectional curvatures.